# Графики в онлайн интерпретаторе python

Tags: python, django, графики

Разрабатываю сайт на Django. На сайте нужно организовать онлайн интерпретатор python (как в интерактивных учебниках). На выводе должны отображаться графики.  Какими средствами можно решить эту задачу?

Comment: http://skulpt.org/

Answer (score 1):

Использую [Plotly](https://plot.ly/). После матплотлиб, это кажется чем-то совершенным. Особенно радует возможность интерактивного взаимодействия

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать django-google-charts и [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/?csw=1) для построения графиков на сайте под управлением Django

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]